# Difficult to get dynamic link-to behavior

Tags: ember.js

I wanted to have a dynamically created `link-to` (a custom semi-back button). This link appears in the `application.hbs`, and is changed on some route changes. I accomplished this by sending an event with `link-to` parameter information:

```
// in patient-route.js
afterModel: function(model) {
  this.send('setHeader', {text: model.get('fullName'), linkTo: 'patient', args: [model.get('id')]});
}
```

and

```
// in application-route.js
actions: {
  setHeader: function(linkTo) {
    linkTo.url = this.router.generate(args.back.route);
    this.set('headerLinkTo', linkTo);
  },
  fakeLinkTo: function(linkTo) {
    this.transitionTo.apply(this, linkTo.args.unshift(linkTo.linkTo));
  }
}
```

with the template looking like

```
<a {{bind-attr href=headerLinkTo.url}} {{action 'fakeLinkTo' headerLinkTo}}>{{headerLinkTo.text}}</a>
```

This is pretty janky, but currently working. This doesn't support active states (although not required for what I need) but it'd be nice if this was easier to do (plus I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be using the router like this).

It seems like a similar problem has crept up in components generating `link-to`'s (for example: http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/#/show_components/tabs-with-routes - can't pass dynamic segments).

What better approaches are there to doing this, or what could there be?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this addon for dynamic links in Ember](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-link), it should support what you're trying to do.